# ANR about Unsafe.park (Native method) in play console

Tags: android, signalr, signalr.client

Using SignalR SDK for android (signalr-client-sdk-android)

after hub proxy connection established getting ANR in play console about

```
 at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park (Native method)
```

[image]

I have checked couple of git issues and stack overflow's ans. but not getting any detail for why this is happening.

Is this ANR affect any specific way to the application? as we are not getting any crash but sometimes apps are lagging.

and this ANR ratio is very high in play console.

Need a solution why this is happening and is there any way to avoid this?